# How to create a new R workspace

Tags: r

I tried resetting my R using the rm comand but now it does not recognize the csv import code. I know the code is right because I gave up and started using my laptop. However, now my R on my desktop is completely useless and I'd rather it not be that way. I have deleted and reinstalled R multiple times and it still refuses to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: On which operating system? What's happening that when you say "it does not recognize the csv import code" is there an error message?

Comment: Please post your csv import code. That's the best way for people to figure out what might be going wrong.+

Comment: You need to elaborate your problem better.

Comment: Do `getwd()` and `setwd()` do anything for you?

Comment: Was that `rm` from within R, or from a shell command line?  What did you delete?  What *does* function when you open R (or R-gui)?

Answer (score 1):

There is potential for corruption of the default saved workspace file which is named `.Rdata`. In both Windows and MacOS, this file is by default invisible (aka a dot-file or system-file). The default history file, `.Rhistory` is also susceptible to corruption. If this is your problem you need to use you system functions from the command line to delete to corrupt files and then restart R.